# PHP JSON to Array Error

Tags: php, foreach, json

I have this code:

```
$decode_dataB = json_decode($grab_dataB, true);
$unranked = '';

foreach($decode_dataB->playerStatSummaries as $summary){
    if($summary->playerStatSummaryType == 'Unranked'){
        $unranked = $summary;
        break;
    }
}
```

for some reason, that I can't figure out, my `$decode_dataB` doesn't work with the `foreach()`. 
I have also tried `$decode_dataB = json_decode($grab_dataB);` it works for most uses of the website, but some get errors.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance

Edit:

Someone wanted `$grab_dataB` although it has nothing to do with the error:

```
$instance = new riotapi($region);
$grab_dataB = $instance->getStats($grab_id);
```

Comment: Can you also show us the data belonging to $grab_dataB?

Comment: "Doesn't work with" "get errors" .......... not a great problem description, that!

Answer (score 4):

Uh... You're passing `true` as the second parameter, thereby getting an associative array.

Why, then, are you treating it like an object? `->` is for getting object properties.

```
foreach($decode_dataB['playerStatSummaries'] as $summary){
    if($summary['playerStatSummaryType'] == 'Unranked'){
        $unranked = $summary;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It got rid of the errors, but now I don't get an output/response ^^'